# DatePicker displaying minutes and seconds SwiftUI

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

Having trouble finding a DatePicker in SwiftUI that displays "mm:ss". displayComponents only has .date and .HourAndMinute.

How do I change the DatePicker to display the minutes and seconds without AM / PM?

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var altEventTime = Date()

public var timeFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss"
    return formatter
}

var body: some View {
    Form {
        DatePicker(selection: self.$altEventTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute) {
            Text("Finish time: \(altEventTime, formatter: timeFormatter)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's unbelievable, that this is not implemented.... Did you find a solution? I took a look into the specifications, there is nothing that supports seconds. So I played around with init and rawValue. Can you conform, that for you the seconds are displayed if you use `displayedComponents: .init(rawValue: 123452135)`?

Comment: I don't know, what is going on.... if you use `displayedComponents: .init(rawValue: 1234521450295224572)` then you'll have day, month, year, hour, minutes and seconds in one field. That's weird

Comment: So if this worked at some point, I can at least now confirm that this is not working any more in Xcode 14 beta 5 (neihter `displayedComponents: .init(rawValue: 123452135)` nor `displayedComponents: .init(rawValue: 1234521450295224572)`...
Still would like to be able to make seconds available...

Comment: As of December 2022, I can confirm that `.init(rawValue: 1234521450295224572)` still works on macOS.

Comment: Using the raw values is no longer working for me :(

Comment: Where does this rawValue come from?